# why doesn't Excluding model properties on update with TryUpdateModel work without ModelState.Remove

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, modelstate

I am trying to update a model by excluding some properties with below code on my controller Action  :

```
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken, ActionName("Edit")]
public ActionResult Edit_post(Board board, int id) {

    var model = _boardrepository.GetSingle(id);

    #region _check if exists

    if (model == null)
        return HttpNotFound();

    #endregion

    if (TryUpdateModel<Board>(model, "", null, new string[] { "BoardID", "BoardGUID", "BoardAbbr" })) { 

        try {

            _boardrepository.Edit(model);
            _boardrepository.Save();

            return RedirectToAction("details", new { id = id });

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            #region Log the error
            ex.RaiseElmahNotification("Error while trying to update a destination.");
            #endregion

            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists, inform your system administrator.");
        }

    }

    return View(board);
}
```

When I try to update my model, it redirects me to my edit view and display a error message saying that `BoardAbbr` field is required which is totally legitimate if I need to update `BoardAbbr` field. But as you can see I am excluding some fields with below code and `BoardAbbr` is one of them :

```
if (TryUpdateModel<Board>(model, "", null, new string[] { "BoardID", "BoardGUID", "BoardAbbr" }))
```

Then I put the below code before `TryUpdateModel` method, it works like a charm :

```
ModelState.Remove("BoardAbbr");
```

What is bothing me here is that either I am doing something wrong or there is something wrong has been built inside the framework. I bet that first one is the issue here.

**why doesn't Excluding model properties on update with `TryUpdateModel` work without `ModelState.Remove`?**

To be honest, I didn't dig into it so much and straightly come here to shout this question to you guys.

Comment: Can you show as the form in your View which is submiting the request to your action?

Answer (score 2):

Your model `Board` probably has a property `BoardAbbr` on it. The message comes from validation of the posted model (Board in this case) and has nothing to do with TryUpdateModel. So if you remove the property on your model the message will go away.

You can see what is happening if you put your `if(TryUpdateModel...` inside an if like this:

```
if(!ModelState.IsValid) {
    if (TryUpdateModel<Board>(model, "", null, new string[] { "BoardID", "BoardGUID", "BoardAbbr" })) { 
  .....
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

As per your comment: excluding the property with a Bind attribute will work:

```
public ActionResult Edit_post([Bind(Exclude="BoardAbbr")] Board board, int id) {
```

But you could also make sure that there is no formvalue coming in that can be bound to the property, the binder will not generate message for properties without formvalues.

Comment: Of course Board model has a property called BoardAbbr but it is coming as null. You say that I need to exclude that with Bind DataAnatation?

Comment: So the propert is nullable on the Board object? If so, maybe you have Required attribute on that property? Maybe you can post the definition of Board.

Comment: You totally got the question wrong. BoardAbbr is not nullable, it is required both on my DAL and Sql Server side. But It is unchangeable. So, there should be no edits on that. the thing which bothers me is that why I need to use ModelState.Remove if I am already excluding the fields on TryUpdateModel method.

Comment: What I'm trying to explain is that modelbinding and validation happen before the code in this action is executed. So ModelState is filled by the modelbinder (maps the formvalues to the parameters of the action) and the modelbinder doesn't know or care that you are going to call TryUpdateModel. So if there is no value that the modelbinder can map to BoardAbbr and that property is not nullable, then ModelState will have the required message added to it. TryUpdateModel does nothing to ModelState.

Comment: To be clear, the message comes from the modelbinder not able to map to the board parameter, not the model variable.